# pandas: how to merge columns irrespective of index

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation

I have two dataframes with meaningless index's, but carefully curated order and I want to merge them while preserving that order. So, for example:

```
>>> df1
   First
a      1
b      3
```

and

```
>>> df2 
c       2
d       4
```

After merging, what I want to obtain is this:

```
>>> Desired_output
                    First  Second
AnythingAtAll           1       2     # <--- Row Names are meaningless.
SeriouslyIDontCare      3       4     # <--- But the ORDER of the rows must be preserved.
```

Every version of "join" I've seen requires me to manually reset indices. I thought `concat` would work, but I get this:

```
>>> pd.concat( [df1, df2] , axis = 1, ignore_index= True )
     0    1
a  1.0  NaN
b  3.0  NaN
c  NaN  2.0
d  NaN  4.0
# ^ obviously not what I want.
```

Even when I explicitly declare `ignore_index`.

How do I "overrule" the indexing and force the columns to be merged with the rows kept in the exact order that I supply them?

---

**Edit**:
Thanks to the suggestion from jsmart and topsail, ***you can dereference the indices by directly accessing the `values` in the column:***

```
df1["second"]=df2["Second"].values
>>> df1
   First  second
a      1       2
b      3       4
```

^ ***Solution***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should also work I think:

```
df1["second"] = df2["second"].values
```

It would keep the index from the first dataframe, but since you have values in there such as "AnyThingAtAll" and "SeriouslyIdontCare" I guess any index values whatsoever are acceptable.

Basically, we are just adding a the values from your series as a new column to the first dataframe.

Here's a test example similar to your described problem:

```
# -----------
# sample data
# -----------
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'x': ['a','b'],
    'First': [1,3],
})
df1.set_index("x", drop=True, inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'x': ['c','d'],
    'Second': [2, 4],
})
df2.set_index("x", drop=True, inplace=True)


# ---------------------------------------------
# Add series as a new column to first dataframe
# ---------------------------------------------
df1["Second"] = df2["Second"].values
```

Result is:

|  | First | Second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 4 |

Comment: I tried that too, but then all of the "second" values in df1 are "NaN" (Which I think is a really crazy standard. It should either assign the values in order, or return an error. The fact that this results in silently assigning NaN everywhere is just.... just not ok. )

Comment: Okay sorry yes I see now. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ignore_index` means whether to keep the output dataframe index from original along `axis`. If it is True, it means don't use original index but start from 0 to n just like what the column header `0, 1` shown in your result.

You can try

```py
out = pd.concat( [df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)] , axis = 1)
```

```
print(out)

   First  Second
0      1       2
1      3       4
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still resetting the index, and then merging based on that new index. Is there no way to just say "Add them by position, and pay no attention at all to the index" ?

Comment: @Jabber1 New index is their position.

Comment: So `.values` throws away the indexing information, and just keeps the values themselves in exactly the order they were originally provided? Great. That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to combine data based on position (not by Index).  Here is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# create data frames df1 and df2
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'First': [1, 3]}, index=['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Second': [2, 4]}, index = ['c', 'd'])

# add a column to df1 -- add by position, not by Index
df1['Second'] = df2['Second'].values

print(df1)
   First  Second
a      1       2
b      3       4
```

And you could create a completely new data frame like this:

```
data = {'1st': df1['First'].values, '2nd': df1['Second'].values}
print(pd.DataFrame(data))

   1st  2nd
0    1    2
1    3    4
```